# On Click of Notification how to open particular page in React native firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-notifications

I want to open a particular page if the notification is clicked. How to do it in React Native?

```js
this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => { 
  this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
   // Process your notification as required 
   // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. 
   // You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification. 

   const { title, body } = notification; }
  );

 const { title, body } = notification; 
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
async setupNotification() {

    firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
        .then((notificationOpen) => {
            if (notificationOpen) {
                // App was opened by a notification
                // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
                const action = notificationOpen.action;
                // Get information about the notification that was opened
                const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
            }
        });

    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
        'channelId',
        'ChannelName',
        firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    ).setDescription('A natural description of the channel');
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    // the listener returns a function you can use to unsubscribe
    this.unsubscribeFromNotificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
        console.log('local notifciation ' + JSON.stringify(notification.data))
        try {
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                    .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
                    .setTitle(notification.title)
                    .setSound('default')
                    .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
                    .setBody(notification.body)
                    .setData(notification.data)
                    .ios.setBadge(notification.ios.badge);
                firebase.notifications()
                    .displayNotification(localNotification)
                    .catch(err => console.error(err));
                // alert('Local notification')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error)
        }

    });


    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
        // alert('Remote notification from killed state to foreground state')
        // App was opened by a notification
        // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened from killed state to foreground
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        // Get information about the notification that was opened
        const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        if (notification.data) { // && Platform.OS !== 'ios'
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.handleNavigation(notification.data);

            }, 100);
        }


        firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications();

    }

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened from background state to foreground
        // alert('Remote notification from background state to foreground state')
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        // Get information about the notification that was opened
        const notification = notificationOpen.notification;

        if (notification.data) { // && Platform.OS !== 'ios'
            setTimeout(() => {

                    this.handleNavigation(notification.data);
                }


            }, 100);
        }
        //Remove delivered notifications from notification tray
        firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
    });


}

=========================
Handle Navigation Method
=========================

    handleNavigation(notif) {

    let type = notif.type ? notif.type : ''

    if (type === 'library') {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')
    }

}
==== Called Setup Notification Method ====
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.setupNotification()
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the getInitialNotification listener 2 times? Is the sequencie important?

Could you please provide more information about your solution?